# Create a ruby Proc from a string

Tags: ruby, lambda

I want to define the block as a string, then create the lambda. 
The following example does not work. 
Is something like this possible?

```
code_string = "|x|x*2"

l = lambda {eval(code_string)}

l.call(3) => 6
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but why in the world do you want to do this? `eval` is almost never the best way to do something, for efficiency's sake if nothing else.

Comment: This definitely seems pretty hacky

Comment: Sometimes you need to generate code "on-the-fly", often from a source that is not Ruby code. I use this technique to implement a transpiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works

```
eval  "lambda { " + code_string + " }"
```

I just don't know why this one does and the other does not.

Comment: Calling lambda on an eval argument results in a Proc object with the eval call 'inside' the Proc object.  The resulting Proc object doesn't take an argument, as the expression `eval(code_string)` doesn't take an argument.  When you call the Proc object, it evals the code_string!

The eval of the string "lambda { " + code_string + " }" gives a Proc object that is expecting an argument, and returns 2*argument.

Comment: Also, it's more idiomatic (and more efficient to boot) to use string interpolation, so it would be: `eval "lambda {#{code_string}}"`. Concatenating several strings with `+` is rarely done in Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

`eval "lambda {#{code_string}}"`